# How to get xml attribute values using encoding/xml package in go language

Tags: go

I need to convert following xml to go struct.

https://play.golang.org/p/tboi-mp06k

```
var data = `<Message xmlns="http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     release="006"
     version="010">`

type Message struct {
   XMLName  xml.Name `xml:http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT "Message"`
   release string `xml:"release,attr"`
   version string `xml:"version,attr"`
}

func main() {

    msg := Message{}
    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &msg)   

   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", msg)
```

}

Program outputs the following:
main.Message{XMLName:xml.Name{Space:"http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT", Local:"Message"}, release:"", version:""}
release and version are empty. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Any parsing (xml or json) works only on exported field. "release" and "version" are unexported, I guess that's why they remain empty.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your struct to:

```
type Message struct {
   XMLName  xml.Name `xml:http://www.ncpdp.org/schema/SCRIPT "Message"`
   Release string `xml:"release,attr"`
   Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
}
```

will solve the issue.
Go uses case to determine whether a particular identifier is public or private within the context of your package. In your code, the fields are not visible to `xml.Unmarshal` because it is not part of the package containing your code.

When you change the fields to be upper case, they became public so could be exported.

Working Example : https://play.golang.org/p/h8Q4t_3ctS